# Specific images cause "500 Internal Error Encountered" -- Google Slides API

Tags: google-slides-api

`Slides.presentations.get(presentationId)` returns the following error when certain images are in a presentation. These images are sometimes in the presentation itself, and sometimes in a Master of a presentation. In either case, the `get` request returns an error when they are present, and succeeds when the images are removed.

Slides API Error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX2EE.png

Error causing image in presentation Master:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSGob.png

We are encountering this issue in the slides presentations of many of our users, and our app requires this request to run. I'm hoping this error can be investigated. I have prepared a public demo presentation, linked below.

Demo Presentation Link:
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1AzeKGTd9HRdefrjQGAAaqCYPqGDhI7NqXPji3CGCTI0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: mind filing a bug on [our issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191598&template=824111)? looks like the image is busted in the editor as well.. please include a link to the source image you tried to insert, if you have it. Thanks!

Comment: will submit a bug to the issue tracker today! unfortunately we do not have the original images that our users inserted to their decks. if I find one I'll send it to you. Thanks for the quick reply!